# Android 5 app that can execute formulas such as 15.50+3.79*2/3

Tags: android, open-source, calculator

The stock Android calculator does not seem to accept formulas.

I often write formulas in emails, for instance when calculating shared costs. So I write this in my email:

```
15.50+3.79*2/3
```

And then I copy it and want to paste it into the calculator.

Is there a calculator that accepts this and gives the result?

Requirements:

- Must be open source.
- Needs to work on Android 5.1.1. Apparently the stock calculator has this feature since Android 6.

Comment: Not sure (I rarely use those). But be welcome to check with my list of [Pocket calculators](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_accessories#group_127) while waiting for an answer (though the result might be you're answering yourself if you were faster ;)

Comment: @Izzy: Do you have a way to filter the open source ones? :-)

Comment: Indirectly and partly, yes: watch out for the F-Droid logo/link next to the app names. Seen e.g. for Calculator, PalmCalc, MathDroid, Clean Calculator, Numix, Arity, WhatExp.

Comment: I just tried pasting that into the Android calculator and it worked. What version of Android are you on? My phone has 6.0.1.

Comment: @BSMP: Actually I can't find any way to paste anything into the calculator... I am using 5.1.1.

Comment: OK, I got a hold of a phone with 5.1 and it looks like the ability to paste into the calculator as if the numbers are in a text field is new. I couldn't find a way of doing it either.